# How to copy one hashmap to another hashmap in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Condition: Copying should be such that the already existing enteries in H1(hashmap1) should get updated (if they have same key) with those of H2 and the one which are not present in H1 should get added.

In java we'have putAll but i couldn't find anything similar in typescript.
I tried doing following:

```
this.stmtTypeMap =stmtMap;
```

but this overwrites the values of **stmtTypeMap** .

My code is:

```
sumBacklog(tpbsDataArray: any) {
        //trust centers
        tpbsDataArray.forEach(element => {
            let stmtMap=new Map<String,Map<String,any>>();
            //category
            element.forEach(stmtDataArr => {
                //console.log(index);
                let stmtStatusMap = new Map<String,any>();
                //Expected, Received, Outstanding
                stmtDataArr.forEach((statusData, index) => {
                    //console.log(index);
                    //debugger;
                    let mySumObject = new mySumObjectClass().mysub;
                    let myTotalObject = new totalSumObjectClass().totalsub;
                    let data = new mySumObjectClass().mysub;
                    let totalData = new totalSumObjectClass().totalsub;

                    if(this.totalMap.has(statusData.STATUS)){
                        totalData = this.totalMap.get(statusData.STATUS);
                        this.sumTotalForExistingMapEnteries(myTotalObject, totalData, statusData);
                        this.totalMap.set(statusData.STATUS,myTotalObject);
                    }else{
                        this.sumTotalForNewMapEnteries(myTotalObject, statusData);
                        this.totalMap.set(statusData.STATUS,myTotalObject);
                    }
                    //console.log(index,stmtDataArr[index].CATEGORY);
                    if(this.stmtTypeMap.has(stmtDataArr[index].CATEGORY)){
                       let categoryData = this.stmtTypeMap.get(stmtDataArr[index].CATEGORY);
                       if(categoryData.has(statusData.STATUS)){
                        data = categoryData.get(statusData.STATUS);
                        this.sumColumnsForExistingMapEnteries(mySumObject, data, statusData);
                        
                        stmtStatusMap.set(statusData.STATUS,mySumObject);
                        stmtMap.set(stmtDataArr[index].CATEGORY, stmtStatusMap);
                       }
                       else{
                        this.sumColumnsForNewMapEnteries(mySumObject, statusData);
 
                        stmtStatusMap.set(statusData.STATUS,mySumObject);
                        stmtMap.set(stmtDataArr[index].CATEGORY, stmtStatusMap);
                       }
                    }
                    else{ 
                        this.sumColumnsForNewMapEnteries(mySumObject, statusData);
                        stmtStatusMap.set(statusData.STATUS,mySumObject);
                        stmtMap.set(stmtDataArr[index].CATEGORY, stmtStatusMap);
                    }
                })
            });
            this.stmtTypeMap =stmtMap;
        });
        return this.stmtTypeMap;
    }
```

Comment: const map1:Map<string, number> = new Map([["key1", 1], ["key2", 2]]);
const map2:Map<string, number> = new Map([["key1", 4], ["key4", 2]]);

const mergedMap: Map<string, number> = new Map([...Array.from(map1.entries()), ...Array.from(map2.entries())]);
console.log(mergedMap); Check this

Comment: could you please suggest me something in my code? I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean an object, you can merge them like this,

```
let map1 = {a:1, b:2};
let map2 = {c:3, b:4};
let mergedMap = {...map1, ...map2};
```

However if you mean a Map object, something like this would work

```
let firstMap: Map<string, number> = new Map([["a", 1], ["b", 2]]);
let secondMap: Map<string, number> = new Map([["c", 3], ["b", 4]]);

let mergedMap: Map<string, number> = new Map([...Array.from(firstMap.entries()), ...Array.from(secondMap.entries())]);
```

Comment: could you please suggest me something in my code? I have edited the question.